# (SCSS - CSS) Grab every second child element

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a CSS Framework for personal usage, that I want to be as "automatic" as possible. And i've met a issue that I cannot solve, but maybe you can help me.

Let's say I have 3 cards where one is the top parent and the rest are children of eachother. I'll show what I mean.

```
<div class="card"> // Top parent
  Lorem!
  <div class="card"> // First child
    Lorem!
    <div class="card"> // Second child
      Lorem!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to have it such that the Parent is styled with an opposing background color from the body and the first child to be the same as the body again so it opposes to the parent card. And the second child to be opposed again to the first child, aka the same background as the top parent. And for this to continue infinitely.

It's possible to use set a background colour for each, but instead of doing this manually I wish for this to happen by itself as you add cards inside other cards.

I am currently solving this doing .card > .card but this only works once, and I don't wish to spam the css with .card > .card > .card > .card > .card etc...

I tried using div:nth-child(even) but this doesn't work if you keep doing children inside one another.

How can I make this possible?

***Current Code:***

**SCSS:**

```
@if #{$class} == card {
/* If parent card has a child card */
.#{$class} > .#{$class} {
  background-color: var(--clr-light-primary-background);
 }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.card > .card {
  background-color: var(--clr-light-primary-background);
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="card column33 sm-rounded">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h2 class="card-title text-regular text-uppercase">TOP PARENT</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h2 class="card-title text-medium">1st CHILD</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h2 class="card-title text-medium">2nd CHILD</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: My Goal]

Comment: `.card > .card > .card > .card > .card` is the way, along with `:not(.card) > .card` etc.

Comment: So there is absolutely no other way other than JS?
I can do JS too, but I don't know how. Do you know?

Comment: You could iterate through your elements using `var parents = document.getElementsByClassName('parentClassName')` and `var children = parents[0].childNodes // this would also need to be iterated` - if you'd like I can try and make a more complete example although I get the feeling I'd get lynched for ugly code.

Comment: Go ahead! I won't judge you :)
I am terrible at making beautiful code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment CSS (AFAIK) does not provide methods to increment CSS vars based on nesting level - why you need to set a finite level of nesting allowed...
but on the other hand would it make sense if your DOM had 20 nested cards ;-)?

Here is a an example that allows 5 nested cards

```css
body {
  --color-text: #fff;
  --color-back: #272b34;
  --color-back-alt: #323743;
  color: var(--color-text);
  background: var(--color-back);
  padding: 1rem;
}

.card {
  background: var(--color-back-alt);
  padding: 1rem;
}

:not(.card)>.card>.card>.card>.card>.card>.card,
:not(.card)>.card>.card>.card>.card,
:not(.card)>.card>.card {
  background: var(--color-back);
}
```

```html
Body
<div class="card"> 1
  <div class="card"> 2
    <div class="card"> 3
      <div class="card"> 4
        <div class="card"> 5
          <div class="card"> 6
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't thnk of a way to do this with CSS that is dynamic enough so here is some JS.

It starts at the outer level card, and then goes on down through them alternating the background color until there are no more.

```js
let odd = true;
let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
do {
  cards[0].style.backgroundColor = (odd) ? 'blue' : 'red';
  odd = !odd;
  cards = cards[0].querySelectorAll('.card');
} while (cards.length > 0)
```

```html
<div class="card column33 sm-rounded">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h2 class="card-title text-regular text-uppercase">TOP PARENT</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h2 class="card-title text-medium">1st CHILD</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h2 class="card-title text-medium">2nd CHILD</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work, but it has one flaw. I know I have to use JS to do this now, as there isn't any Pure CSS ways of doing it. But using JS it adds style="" to the element.

JS can change the CSS though I believe.
Is there a relevant way of adding JS to SCSS?

Comment: Not sure I understand - SCSS being a preprocessor. Are you wanting to get the JS to update the CSS stylesheet? I am probably missing something but I'm not sure how that would help. You could add a class to the card instead of altering its inline style and have a couple of classes if that makes it easier to change things later, but I can't see how altering the CSS could help.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS solution**

This is probably not practical for a CSS framework, but you could play around with CSS filters and see if you can get a colour combination that works.

Note the JS here is just for the demo.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  const lastCard = cards[cards.length - 1];

  lastCard.innerHTML = `${cards.length} <div class="card">${
    cards.length + 1
  }</div>`;
});

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const newColor = e.target.value;

  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--card-bg-color", newColor);
});
```

```css
:root {
  --card-bg-color: #666;
}

.card {
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: var(--card-bg-color);
  >
}

.card>.card {
  filter: invert(100%);
}


/* Demo */
.control {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: .5rem;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">1
  <div class="card">2
    <div class="card">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Demo -->
<div class="control">
  <button>Add card</button>
  <label for="color">Change colour <input type="color" value="#666666"></label>
</div>
```

**JavaScript solution**

```js
const setCardBackgroundColors = () => {
  const cards = [...document.querySelectorAll(".card")];

  cards && cards.length && cards.forEach((card, index) => {
    index % 2 && card.classList.add('has-bg-dark');
  })
}


// Just for demo
const template = (level) => {
  return `
    <article class="card">
       <p>${level}</p>
    </article>
    `
}
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  const lastCard = cards[cards.length - 1];

  lastCard.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template(cards.length + 1));
  setCardBackgroundColors();
});
```

```css
.card {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  position: relative;
}

.card.has-bg-dark {
  background-color: #222;
}

/* demo styles */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 18px/1.2 system-ui;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.control {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<article class="card">
  <p>1</p>
</article>

<!-- Demo -->
<div class="control">
  <button>Add card</button>
</div>
```

Comment: While it's a genius way of doing it with pure CSS there isn't any way of controlling the invert colour it seems. So it won't be practical to use in this enviroment. Thank you for the idea though!

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to get the effect you want with pure CSS, or SCSS. Are you open to JavaScript solutions?

Comment: Yes @sol absolutely.

Comment: Added. You just need to loop through your cards and add a class you can target with your CSS. The function here assumes just one `.card` parent on the page. You may need to modify it for your needs.